# Creating fixed width polygons in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, polygon-creation

I've been adding easements, which typically have a fixed width. Are there any existing tools or scripts that would allow me to define one edge and automatically create the other? The buffer tool is poor, the line offset tool is for lines.

I want to be able to use the same tools (sketch, intersect, endpoint arc) and have actual curves,not point approximations (what buffer does).

Comment: In what way(s) is the buffer tool "poor"?

Comment: The buffer tool does not do beveled/mitered and it approximates 2 vertex curves with 100 vertex curves. Further, it buffers both sides which means extra work. I can do it more quickly and better with just the sketch tool and CTRL+F->"90"->CTRL+L->"width"

Comment: Did you ever create this tool? I need the same thing and can't find a good solution other than drawing the one side of the polygon first and then using the copy parallel command and then tracing a polygon over these two polylines.

Comment: @Paul I haven't. I may still, logically it should be easier now than it was almost 3 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you need COGO tools

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=An_overview_of_COGO
(ArcEditor/ArcInfo required)

Comment: hm, not really. I've got parcel polygons to trace the edge of so I usually don't need to use direction/distance measurements at all. I'm thinking I'll have to create the tool myself.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help also.

[parallel line](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Copying_parallel_line_features)

You didn't say if you have 10 or not.

Here is the [10 version](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Copying_parallel_line_features/001t00000033000000/) and [tracing](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Creating_segments_by_tracing/001t00000032000000/) may have some benfit for discussion